# How to Get Lattitude and Longitude of US Interstate Exits programmatically?

Tags: geolocation

Is there a way to do that using open source map / API (Google Map API, Microsoft Live Map API)?

Or is there a way to traverse roads and junction from map files? (if I purchase commericial map data)

Thanks.

Edit: Either open source or API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution based on openstreetmap depending on the quality of OSM data in the US.

As described here ["Exit ramps/slip roads should be tagged as highway=motorway_link or highway=primary_link"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Roads) if you import the map data for the US (using *osm2pgsql*) you can then select all motorway links.

E.g. (selects based on my own data, i.e. very much outside US)

```
openmapdb=# select osm_id, name, ref from planet_osm_roads where highway='motorway_link';
  osm_id  | name | ref 
----------+------+-----
 23683997 |      | 
 26436348 |      | 
 [..]
```

[23683997](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/23380767) and [26436348](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/26436348) are the OSM ids - if you click on the links you'll see they are indeed entry/exit ramps.

Once you've identified a way, you can access the latitude and logitude:

```
openmapdb=# select astext(st_transform(way, 4326)) from planet_osm_roads where osm_id = '23683997';                                                                                                                                             
    LINESTRING(24.8757131412186 44.8730730514894,[..]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you. It definitely helped.

Comment: Hey, I'm thinking of starting a project that needs this solution. Did it end up working out for you, 47d_?