# How to map given latitude longitude to interstate in USA

Tags: java, reverse-geocoding

Any type of information for Java will help like API, etc.

Comment: What data do you have for the Interstate?  Also, see this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/1960661/643500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org).  Keep in mind the process you are interested in is called Reverse Geocoding.  One such option they perform is to return nearest streets associated with lat/long pairs like you need.  You feed an encoded url.  You get back a JSON result or an XML result, your choice.  That should be simple enough in Java.  An example url to get your started is try the following:

[example](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyStreets?lat=38.999&lng=-77.1462&username=demo)