# Lat-Long of exits on a Freeway e.g US 101 say arranged in N-S direction

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis

I am trying to find all exits on `US 101` exits, preferably in the order North to South using the `OpenGIS osm2pgsql`. But no luck  so far.

Closes solution I found is:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960005/how-to-get-lattitude-and-longitude-of-us-interstate-exits-programmatically` comes close with the SQL:

```
select osm_id, name, ref from planet_osm_roads where highway='motorway_link';
```

The query:

```
select osm_id, name, ref from planet_osm_roads where highway='motorway';
```

Returns a lot more nodes with ref but I dont think those are freeway exits (whats special about the points noted on the freeway where highway="motorway"?

However most of the exits have null name and ref so while I have exit lat-longs its not clear which freeway these exits are on and nor are they ordered say North to South..

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an [Overpass](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) query that gives you all ways tagged as `highway=motorway_link` that are connected to ways tagged `[ref="US 101"]`:

```
[timeout:60][bbox:19.56,-132.63,51.62,-56.60];
way[highway][ref="US 101"];
node(w);
way(bn)[highway=motorway_link];
out center;
```

You can then export the data as GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1):

In OSM data motorway exit is tagged with [highway=motorway_junction](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dmotorway_junction), and it's type of point, so:

```
select * 
from planet_osm_point 
where highway = 'motorway_junction' 
 and ref = '101' 
order by ST_Y(way) desc
```

If there is a problem with empty ref on this points you can also check if there is some motorway with specified ref (of course it's not a 100% method but better than no method)

```
select * 
from planet_osm_point p 
where highway = 'motorway_junction' 
 and exists (
  select 1 
  from planet_osm_lines l 
  where st_DWithin(l.way::geography, p.way::geography, 100)
   and highway = 'motorway'
   and ref = '101')
order by ST_Y(way) desc
```

Comment: Hi Jendrusk - Looks like Ref is the exit number like (495A) not the freeway name (like 101) in planet_osm_point so the first query did not get me very far. Any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: Yes - try second query - this will give you all points with highway = 'motorway_junction' which are nearer than 100m from any line with highway = 'motorway' with ref = '101'. You can get few incorrect points, but If we don't have straight relation i can't see any other way